# isInView not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

when I comment out '$(".div").css('visibility','initial'); then the div stays hidden, and is not displayed on the screen. However, if do include it in 'if (isInView)' then the div is displayed despite whether it meets the if condition, i.e. it's always displayed. I have added a console log into the if statement, and it works accurately - only prints when the div is in view. Anyone have any ideas on why this isn't applicable to the div css change?

```
$(".div-intro").on('inview', function(event, isInView) {

  if (isInView) {
  //    $(".div").css('visibility','initial');
  }else{
    console.log("error");
  }
});

.div { visibility:hidden;}
```

Comment: Can you please confirm your `isInView` function? Are you using the jQuery [**isInView plugin**](https://github.com/hashchange/jquery.isinview)?

Comment: @ObsidianAge yeah that's the one I'm using :)

Answer (score 3):

Define new Jquery function like this to determine if an element is in the viewport.

Add after include Jquery:

```
$.fn.isInViewport = function() {
  var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
  var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();

  var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

  return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};
```

Usage:

```
    $(window).on('resize scroll', function() {
     if ($('#Something').isInViewport()) {
         //IN - Some code...
     } else {
         //OUT - Some code...
     }
});
```

Snippet show:

```js
$.fn.isInViewport = function() {
var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();

var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};

    $(window).on('resize scroll', function() {
    
     if ($('.check1').isInViewport()) {
     
         //IN
         $('.check1')
         .delay(800)
         .queue(function (next) { 
         $(this).css('background', '#BADA55');
         next(); 
         });
         
         
     } else {
     
         //OUT
         $('.check1').css('background', 'black');
         
     }
     
     if ($('.check2').isInViewport()) {
     
         //IN
         $('.check2')
         .delay(800)
         .queue(function (next) { 
         $(this).css('background', '#BADA55');
         next(); 
         });
         
     } else {
     
         //OUT
         $('.check2').css('background', 'black');
  
     }
     
});
```

```css
div{
  height:100vh;
  background:grey;
  border-bottom:1px solid white;
}

ul{
position:fixed;

}

  li{
    color:white;
     font-family:sans-serif;
  }

div span{
  color:white;
  font-size:106px;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-weight:bold;
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="check1"><span>1</span></div>
<div class="check2"><span>2</span></div>
```